# Finding value of a variable that maximises one function at the same time as it minimises another

Tags: functions, optimization

I have two functions of a single variable r. I would like to find the value of r that maximises one function whilst at the same time minimises the other, or at least have a plot of values where the criteria above apply. Do I just plot both functions and see where they cross each other?

Comment: This Q would be better if you put in a clearer statement of what you understand about the problem.  Maybe you have a simple example in mind that you could use to make clear what you are thinking.  For me, I wonder what your answer would be in the particular case $f(r)=r$ and $g(r)=r+1$.  How can there be an $r$ that maximizes one and minimizes the other?  Maybe there is some side restriction you forgot to mention?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a multi-objective function optimization problem. Since it is univariate, graphical solution can be easily obtained.
Otherwise, you can try more sophisticated methods if you have derivative information of the functions, by doing Newton's Method.

Comment: One function is cr(x) = c(x^2-1) looking to minimize. The other is cp(x) = ke^x looking to maximize